# Trying to download a directory from index page using wget

Tags: bash, file, curl, command-line, wget

Hello I am trying to download the "Inspector" directory from http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/tabs/

I tried using curl first but no success then I installed wget and tried the following command bit still dint work.All that i got is only index.html file!

```
wget -r -np -k http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/tabs/inspector/
```

How can i download the entire inspector directory.There are many such questions and i have tried almost all the solutions given.
And I dont want to use any gui tool.PLease tell me a way to do this from cmd.

I am MAC OS Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `-e robots=off` in the wget command